# Function composition in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I need to implement a function (`flow`) that makes a functional composition of its two arguments.

Requirements:

- The `flow` function should take two functions as arguments (called `fab` and `fbc`) and return a new function that applies `fab` to its input parameter and then applies `fbc` to the resulting value.

Hints:

- The first function is called `fab` because it maps a value from type `A` to type `B`. The same for `fbc`.

The problem is that I don't know what to pass as a parameter to fab function, I'm a Typescript newbie, would appreciate any help!

This is my code so far:

```
type Flow = <A, B, C>(
  fab: (a: A) => B, // Takes a function from A to B
  fbc: (b: B) => C // Takes a function from B to C
) => (a: A) => C; // Returns a function from A to C

export const flow: Flow = (fab, fbc) => {
  return fbc(fab());
};
```

Comment: `return a => fbc(fab(a));`   https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgewO5QLxQDwEEA0UBCeAwgHwAUAUFFAGYCGARgFxRl0tYCUaJBeA9PygAVOgGsIAZyh1aAVwB2AY2ABLBAtoAnBAFsoWKMAQEqtBkpZlmBbql5EogkeKkz5ytRu16CRk0QUdrxsHMFQRADcTkIAShDAcloK0rI0iirqmjQ6+obGERQUEAAeYAhawFBKGpJVNIhILPDIaKz0DHg0FuEA3mZaCUmasvbmSmQdbJyckRQAvnMUQA

Comment: might be worth looking at how lodash does this  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/527b5d43788a2e726470d8b37f567d236864b778/types/lodash/common/util.d.ts#L175

Comment: @Keith thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Flow = <A, B, C>(
  fab: (a: A) => B, // Takes a function from A to B
  fbc: (b: B) => C // Takes a function from B to C
) => (a: A) => C; // Returns a function from A to C

export const flow: Flow = (fab, fbc) => (a) => fbc(fab(a));
```